# Why website Contact form is not working?

Tags: php, forms, email

I have written the following contact form. But it is or working. Please help me ....

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $ToEmail = 'mymail@gmail.com';
        $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form ';
        $mailheader = "From: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
        $mailheader .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
        $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: " . $_POST["name"] . "<br>";
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "<br>";
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: " . nl2br($_POST["comment"]) . "<br>";
        mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) 
        or die("Failure");

        echo "<p>Your message was sent.</p>"; 
    }         
?>

<form action="index.php?page=contacts" method="post">                
    <p>Your name:<br/>
        <input name="name" type="text"  size="32">
    </p>
    <p>Email address:<br/>
        <input name="email" type="text"  size="32">
    </p>
    <p>Message:<br/>
        <textarea name="comment" cols="55" rows="8"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">
    </p>
</form>
```

If you find any bug please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is it failing? Are you getting an error, or incorrect results?

Comment: Define "not working."  How does it fail?  On what line does it fail?  Is there an error message?  For example, does the call to `mail()` produce an error in your logs?

Comment: i don't get mails. Web page shows Failure.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is the form is erroring? the email not sending? I'd suggesting establishing first off whether your mail block is being entered, this should help isolote the issue. EDIT: What failure is it showing? please show us!

Comment: mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) 
                or die("Failure");  <-this function works but mail() function doesn't

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how `die()` works. `die()` is being called *because* your call to the mail function is failing.

Comment: i know that and i want to know why mail() is not working..

Comment: You should probably echo your parameters prior to sending the mail to ensure they are populated, the 'From' field for example might be empty.

Comment: why i got a -1 in this post!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if mail() returns false, then your PHP isn't configured properly. If you're on a Windows host, you need to have valid [`SMTP`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp) and [`smtp_port`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp-port) settings defined in your php.ini, and the SMTP server must be up and running.

That, or you're passing in bad values for the 'To:' or other headers that the SMTP server is rejecting outright.

Answer (score 0):

You're submit button has a name of "Submit", yet you are checking for "submit". Case is sensitive while dealing with Get/Post variables.

Other than that it looks like it'll work. Although, it would be a good idea to clean the data before sending it via email. Something like this would be better:

```
<?php
            if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                $ToEmail = 'sustcorpus@gmail.com';
                $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form ';
                $mailheader = "From: " . htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($_POST["email"]))) . "\r\n";
                $mailheader .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
                $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: " . htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]))) . "<br>";
                $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: " . htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($_POST["email"]))) . "<br>";
                $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: " . nl2br(htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($_POST["comment"])))) . "<br>";
                mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) 
                or die("Failure");

            echo "<p>Your message was sent.</p>"; 
        }

        ?>
            <form action="index.php?page=contacts" method="post">

                        <p>Your name:<br/>
                        <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']?>"  size="32">
                        </p>
                        <p>Email address:<br/>
                        <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']?>"  size="32">
                        </p>
                        <p>Message:<br/>
                        <textarea name="comment" cols="55" rows="8"><?php echo $_POST['comment']?></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">
                        </p>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Php is case-sensitive, change

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

with:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
```

because in your form you have written the name of the submit button with: **Submit**